# Error in Java line code

Tags: java, line

http://pastebin.com/gDMy7fPw

Above, Is my code for a shape creator, this is one part but stands alone.

I get an error on

```
g2d.drawLine(p1.getX(), p1.getY(), p2.getX(), p2.getY());
```

which basically says that it *Cannot invoke getX() on the primitive type double*, *Cannot invoke getY() on the primitive type double*.

I can change any code except that method. Does anyone know how I can get rid of that error as I don't know what it means.

Answer (score 6):

Your `p1` and `p2` variables are of type `double`. The *first* thing to do is work on your understanding. The compiler message says everything you should need:

> Cannot invoke getX() on the primitive type double

It's absolutely right - you can't call `getX()` on `double`. So next you should work out *why* you're trying to call `getX()` at all. Should you not be calling it, or is the type of your variable wrong?

I *suspect* that instead of these variables:

```
private double x1;
private double y1;
private double x2;
private double y2;
private double p1;
private double p2;
```

you actually want:

```
private Point p1;
private Point p2;
```

Alternatively, get rid of `p1` and `p2` completely, and change your call to:

```
g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

Comment: +1; also note that "Cannot invoke XYZ() on the primitive type double" means the variable you've tried to invoke the method on (in this case, `getX()` and `getY()` is not an object, but rather a primitive type (like `int`, `double`, `float`, `byte`, etc...).  Primitive types have no methods.

Comment: +1 for the `Point p1` change. You can safely delete the "Alternatively..." part of your answer, because the OP says that he "can change any code except that method".

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I think I'll leave it in there for the sake of other people who *can* make other thanges :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you wanted to use:

g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

Comment: Unfortunetly, I can't change it to that as the assignment specification gives the following code                          public void renderShape(Graphics2D g2d) {
  g2d.drawLine(p1.getX(), p1.getY(), p2.getX(), p2.getY());  
 }                                                             And I have to work around that.